# How to find 2nd highest bar?

Tags: pine-script, trendline

I used highestbars(length) to find out the highest bar as the first point of  downward trend line.And I need the second highest bars as the second point of downward trend line.At the begin,I use:

```
x1:=-1*highestbars(length)
x2:=-1*highestbars(x1-interval)  
//interval = 15 as distance between highest and 2nd highest point.
```

and I got error message of  "Cannot call 'highestbars' with arguments (series[integer]); available overloads: highestbars(series[float], integer) => series[integer]; highestbars(integer) => series[integer]"

then I wrote a code to find out the 2nd highest bar:

```
//@version=4
study("Triangle",overlay=false)

length=input(title="Length",type=input.integer,defval=244)
// interval=input(title="Distance between 2 high",type=input.integer,defval=50)
// long=input(title="Distance from 1 high",type=input.integer,defval=80)

x1=int(0)
y1=float(0)
x2=int(0)
y2=float(0)

x1:=-1*highestbars(length)
y1:=high[x1]

for i=x1-1 to 1
    if high[i] > y2
        x2:=i
        y2:=high[i]

//plot(x1,color=color.red)
plot(x2,color=color.yellow)
```

But I cannot plot x2,don't know why,thanks help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXQ05.png)

Answer (score 0):

Needed a special case for when the highest high is on the current bar:

```
//@version=4
study("Triangle",overlay=true)

length=input(title="Length",type=input.integer,defval=10)

x1=int(0)
y1=float(0)
x2=int(0)
y2=float(0)

x1:= - highestbars(length)
y1:=high[x1]

if x1 == 0
    // Special case for when highest is on the current bar.
    x2 := 0
else
    for i=x1-1 to 0
        if high[i] > y2
            x2:=i
            y2:=high[i]

plot(high[x1],color=color.silver, linewidth=6, transp=60)
plot(high[x2],color=color.yellow)
```

[image]